# Puzzled by MySQL information_schema.tables info

Tags: mysql, myisam, information-schema

For some unknown reason, the info of 'information_schema.tables' is not match to real tables:

**First**, find table-name from information_schema.tables, there is one result;
Then, select * from table-name, it shows table not exist!  /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

I try to create a new table(MyISAM engine) with same name, it create OK!
Then, find table-name from information_schema.tables, there are two result!
And select * from table-name shows empty set, it's normally.

Until now, table can be use, but can not be drop completely.
If drop table, it return the "First".

**As the following image:** 
[all the step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QBvw.png)

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this......

Comment: You could try to insert the image directly into the question, not everyone follows links..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I have not enough reputation to insert a image directly(I think so)... /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~ @StefanHegny

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/database-use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image shows nothing wrong to me. When you run this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'report_instance_performance_20160614
```

and get a result, you are probably getting a result for a table of that name in a different schema from where you ran that query. It would be more helpful to run this to see if something were wrong:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'report_instance_performance_20160614'
```

My assertion that that table exists in another schema but not that one that you're running in the query from is that you're getting the `doesn't exist` error when you try and `SELECT` from it.

Next, when you create a new instance of that table and then run your `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` query, you are getting two results because you've now created a table with that name in your current schema. If that table had existed in your current schema, you would've gotten an error that a table of that name already existed in the schema. This further supports my assertion that `report_instance_performance_20160614` exists in a different schema.

Lastly, since the table is newly created and you haven't `INSERT`ed anything into the table before `SELECT`ing from it, it's totally normal that the table would be empty.

Comment: Yes... you are correct. there is another schema... Thank You Very Much! I'm so sorry for this question, Because of my limited MySQL knowledge, the understanding of the "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" is not enough thorough...

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct then to help others who come and see this question :)